# Auto need a power source ONLY on when car is off. So when car is on this source of 12V power would be OFF

Tags: power-supply, automotive

Yes, the opposite of what is usually asked for.

I need to charge a device ONLY when the car is stationary and the ignition off. This is needed because the device doesn't work while its charging.

I am looking to power a 12 V to 5 V, 2000 mA charger. Basically a cell phone car charger.
The device to be charged will not operate while it's being charged.
The goal is to keep it charged so that while the car ignition is on, car is moving the device is charged.

So far all I can think of is 12 V timer operated switch that I can set to charge device a few hours every night while car is stationary.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: watersouprty 12V DC Infinite Cycle Delay Timing Timer Relay ON Off Switch Loop Module Trigger

Answer (score 5):

A 12V, SPDT relay can do this. Use the relay's normally-closed contacts to connect the device to BATT when the key is off.

Basic idea:

- ACC On: Relay is energized, disconnecting the device from BATT
- ACC Off: Relay is deenergized, connecting the device to BATT

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMtYjWm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>